# List setting in MS Word VBA is slow

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to apply the same font, font size and spacing to all list bullets (including numbered lists) in a MS Word file. The following current code works very slow. I suppose it is because it uses Selection, but I do not know an alternative solution.

How to speed up the code?

```vb
Dim p As Paragraph

For Each p In ActiveDocument.ListParagraphs
    p.SelectNumber
    With Selection
        .Font.Size = 10.5
        If .Font.Name <> "Symbol" And .Font.Name <> "Wingdings" And .Font.Name <> "Courier New" Then
            .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        End If
        .Font.Scaling = 100
        .Font.Spacing = 0
    End With
Next p
```

Comment: You are doing multiple selections, which slows things down.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering another way without using Selection...

Comment: If your document uses Word correctly you would just change the relevant properties of the appropriate List style.

Comment: I have a lot of word documents converted from pdf files, so they have a large variety of listing styles in terms of font size, spacing, etc. I want to apply the same style to them.

Comment: It is called using the range instead of the selection. I am unsure, though, whether you can do this with numberselect. You might try turning screen updating off at the beginning and back on at the end. Word documents converted from any other format are always going to be very difficult to edit, because they do not use Word's methods to accomplish tasks.

Comment: I suppose the code uses Selection, and Range seems it does not support selectnumber. Is it misunderstanding?